# Can I change the Hasura Graphql Endpoint?

Tags: graphql, hasura

Is it possible to change the default endpoints like /v1/graphql to something like this /service-name/v1/graphql?

Comment: Answer by @ShinaBR2 is absolutely correct. Also I suspect that you asked about customizing endpoints using only `graphql-engine serve` settings. If so - I see no such settings both in documentation and `graphql-engine serve --help`

Comment: Alex Yu, you're correct. You can't change the context path of hasura itself. but using reverse proxy stated by @ShinaBR2 then I can still achieve the idea that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally you can.

Depends on how you deploy Hasura, for example I'm using Docker with Caddy on DigitalOcean. My endpoint should be: `http://mydomain-for-example.com/v1/graphql`. You need to config your reverse proxy (nginx, apache, caddy) to map the above `mydomain-for-example.com` to map with the Hasura docker instance.

Comment: Yes they are almost the same, you can see more [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/753105/how-to-reverse-proxy-to-different-places-depending-on-subdomain-in-nginx) as an example.

Comment: I don't understand who minused this answer - it's totally valid. Although I suppose that OP asked about is there a way to customize endpoints using only `graphql-engine serve`